# Necessity of java web-frameworks when using AngularJS

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, web-services

We are currently developing an enterprise web application (Java backend + HTML/JS frontend). This application shall provide cloud-based data analysis functionality to a variety of users. Now, we have decided to use AngularJS for creating the web-frontend. The communication to the backend is realized with REST webservices (implemented in java using jersey, and jetty as webserver).

Some time ago, I have already developed simple java web apps using apache wicket just for examplary reasons. Since I am new to AngularJS, I am wondering if there is any reason why it could still be necessary for us to use a java web-framework (such as wicket, gwt, etc.) additionally to Angular JS? 
The other way around: since we use Angular for developing the web-frontend, we do not need any web-framework on the java side any more, right?

I am quite new to java web applications, so any help would really be appreciated :-)

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS has the $http service which should be able to handle all your GET/POST requests that you need to make to your Java backend. The docs for it are here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

As long your return data is properly formatted JSON or whichever format you want, Javascript should read it just fine. AngularJS should be fine for your project.